# Inserting multiple strings into 1 table

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I am trying to add 2 strings into a table.

My insert statement is:

```
  INSERT INTO "State"
       (state, relevant_id)
       VALUES (%s, %s) """, state_values, relevant_id
```

This does not work because I am supplying too many arguments. Relevant_id is a variable that holds an integer, while state_values are values pertaining to the relevant_id.

Is there a way to insert both strings coming from 2 different variables? I am coding in python and using postgres as a db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass query parameters as a tuple in a second argument to `execute`:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO 
                      State 
                      (state, relevant_id)
                  VALUES 
                      (%s, %s);""",
               (state_values, relevant_id))
```

If you do it this way, you'll also get escaping to prevent sql injections for free.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I guess I didn't put the entire code in there but the code above is wrapped around the cursor.execute function.

Comment: Well, I think you didn't put parameters in a tuple as I did. Please check.

Comment: You're right. Sorry I didn't catch the tuple syntax. Thanks for your help. You solve it.